# Listen on event between some parent and some child element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I have a modal that covers whole window, but only because there is a need for a darkening background to the modal that is set on `.open.modal`. HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="modals">
  <div class="open modal">
    <div class="modal_inner">
      <div class="white">
        <div class="x"><img src="/assets/meeting/close.png"></div>
        <div class="all">
            <!-- ALL CONTENT HERE -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="open modal">
    <!-- OTHER MODAL CAN BE OPEN ON TOP -->
  </div>
</div>
```

When user clicks outside `.white` (`.open.modal` or above) I want to close the modal.

How do I register a Javascript event that will fire if clicked between the parent (in this case `body` or bellow) and the child (in this case `.white`)?

I have this in React.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two standard ways to approach it:

#### Multiple handlers

1. Hook `click` on `.open.modal` and do the real work there
2. Hook `click` on `.white` and prevent bubbling, so clicks on `.white` don't reach `.open.modal`, and thus don't trigger its handler

So for instance:

```
handleOpenModalClick(event) {
    // Do the work
}
handleWhiteClick(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Example:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  handleOpenModalClick(event) {
    // Do the work
    console.log("Do it");
  }
  handleWhiteClick(event) {
      event.stopPropagation();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="open modal" onClick={this.handleOpenModalClick}>
          <div className="white" onClick={this.handleWhiteClick}>
            xxx
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
.open.modal {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
}
.white {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="react"</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

#### Filtering the event once received

Hook `click` on `.open.modal`, and when received, check the elements between `event.target` and `.open.modal` and check if `.white` is there. If so, don't do the work.

```
handleClick(event) {
    let node = event.target;
    while (node && node !== event.currentTarget) {
        if (node.classList.contains("white")) {
            return; // Skip it
        }
    }
    // Do the work
}
```

Example:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  handleClick(event) {
    let node = event.target;
    while (node && node !== event.currentTarget) {
      if (node.classList.contains("white")) {
        return; // Skip it
      }
    }
    // Do the work
    console.log("Do it!");
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="open modal" onClick={this.handleClick}>
          <div className="white">
            xxx
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
.open.modal {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
}
.white {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="react"</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! .. Can you provide an example for first approach? Either in JS or React. Btw, you probably mean the `.open.modal` and not `.modal_inner` as it is a wrapper for `.white`

Comment: Thanks, looks nice, so the event in `handleWhiteClick` will be the same exact event as in `handleOpenModalClick`?

Comment: @Aurimas: No, they'd be quite different, as shown. `handleWhiteClick`'s only job is `stopPropagation()`. `handleOpenModalClick`'s job is to do whatever it is you want to do there (dismiss the modal, I'm guessing).

Comment: @Aurimas: I *assume* so, I've never actually proven to myself that's true cross-browser (and within React, which does some special event handling). But if you call `stopPropagation` on it in `handleWhiteClick`, that will reliably prevent it ever reaching `handleOpenModalClick` at all, so the point is moot...?

Comment: I guess so. Anyway, thanks, I just added `onClick={() => {this.props.store.dispatch(closeAllModals())}}` on `.open.modal` and `onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}` to `.white` and it works like a charm ;) I will leave the question unaccepted if anyone would come up with something even more creative and then accept it. Thanks again.